# Intercept response headers in angular

Tags: angular, interceptor, response-headers

I am creating an token based authentication system in angular5. With every request I will send a header containing the token (`X-SDB-AUTH-TOKEN`) and with some response with 401 or 403 status code I sed a response header to identify the type of foribidden status like forbidden because key not match return response header `AUTH-STATUS :1`  and if user not active status `AUTH-STATUS:2` etc.. I want to check in the interceptor and if the status code is `401 or 403` and if `AUTH-STATUS:2` redirect to `user not active page` otherwise if the status code is `401 or 403` and if `AUTH-STATUS:1` redirect to `key not match page`. How can I verify response code and header value together. How can we easily read response headers and error code. My code till now is

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

 @Injectable()
    export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
 }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

if (localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {    
  req = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      'X-SDB-AUTH-TOKEN': localStorage.getItem('authToken')
    }
  });

}
return next.handle(req)
  .catch((error, caught) => {
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
       localStorage.removeItem('authToken');  
       this.router.navigate(['/testLogin']);   
    }

    return Observable.throw(error);
  }) as any;
 }  
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? Or redirect doesn't work?

Comment: @AndreiMihalciuc The redirect is working properly without any errors. What I want is if the status code is 401 or 403 and based on the `AUTH-STATUS` header I need to redirect to two diffrent page

Comment: Do you mean that you can't get the value of AUTH-STATUS header?

Comment: @AndreiMihalciuc yes

Comment: @AndreiMihalciuc I am getting it in the response header but how I can fetch it in the interceptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `catch` operator has two parameters `.catch((error, caught) => {})`.

`error` is of type [HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse), it has a field `headers` which allows you to get access to the headers collection.

Comment: Yes when I log the error object I have seen the headers but how can I read that can u help

Comment: I used ' console.log(err.headers.keys())' but it is returning only  '"pragma","content-type","cache-control","expires"` .It is not returning my custom header and some other headers like 'Content-Length'

Comment: In my browser response header I can see all the headers but when I logged it in the angular side it is not listing that

Comment: When asking a question please be more specific. You have to configure your backend to to be in the list of the header Access-Control-Expose-Headers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616757/angular-2-http-observable-request-not-returning-response-header