# angular 6 get Response headers inside interceptor

Tags: angular, interceptor

Can not retrieve response headers inside angular 6 interceptor service though it's available in chrome console network tab.I found many solution for the same and add all of it,but nothing happened. I add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in my node.js server.

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization,Auth');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Autho')
```

Also I'm using `HTTPClient` module for rest api .

Interceptor.ts file:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
const token = sessionStorage.getItem('data');
const id = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
const re = '/login';
// if( !token)
 console.log(request.url);
// console.log(new URL(request.url).searchParams.get('userId'));

if (request.url.search(re) === -1) {
  request = request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: token,
      Auth: id
    }
  });
}
return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  console.log(event);
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    // do stuff with response if you want
    console.log(event.headers);
    // console.log(response.headers);
    // console.log(HttpResponse.Headers);
  }
}, (err: any) => {
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.status === 400) {
      // redirect to the login route
      // or show a modal
      console.log('ERROR');
      window.location.href = this.messageService.API_ROOT;
    }
  }
});
}
```

console.log(event.headers); prints nothing.

rest-api.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';


 const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
 };

  @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
   })
 export class RestApiService {

 apiRoot = 'http://localhost:9005';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 }

  addModule(data) {
   return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + '/addModule', data, httpOptions);
 }

 getModules() {
   return this.http.get(this.apiRoot + '/getModules');
 }
}
```

Server :

```
 res.setHeader('Autho','xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

Adding the header like this .
How to get the 'Autho' header field inside the interceptor

Answer (score 2):

I was running into same issue, and this post is the first response in Google, but does not contain what I think is the right answer.  No idea how OP managed to get it work with their solution.  It turns out that since HttpClient is using XmlHttpRequest, that there needs to be a "control" header present to allow angular to see the headers that Chrome Network can see.  This post has the details : [Angular 2 http Observable request not returning response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616757/angular-2-http-observable-request-not-returning-response-header)

I added it to my express backend and everything works as expected (and I'm doing a very similar thing to what @Subham was trying.

This is with Angular 9.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by putting `console.log(event.headers.get('Autho'));` inside interceptor file after the `console.log(event.headers);`.I don't know the exact reason but I think angular is doing some lazy loading and they only provide the necessary data like reponse body.So only when we ask for some data like using  `get('Autho')` they provide that data.

updated interceptor.ts :

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('data');
    const id = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
    const re = '/login';
    // if( !token)
    console.log(request.url);
    // console.log(new URL(request.url).searchParams.get('userId'));

    if (request.url.search(re) === -1) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: token,
          Auth: id
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      console.log(event);
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
        console.log(event.headers);
        const jwt = event.headers.get('Autho');
        console.log(jwt);
        // console.log(response.headers);
        // console.log(HttpResponse.Headers);
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.status === 400) {
          // redirect to the login route
          // or show a modal
          console.log('ERROR');
          window.location.href = this.messageService.API_ROOT;
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast headers to HttpHeaders like this

```
....
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        let headers: HttpHeaders = event.headers
        console.log(headers.get('Autho')) 
    }
....
```